# Does CS:GO have a default rank when you've reached 10 competitive wins?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm totally new to CS:GO and I have utter crap skills in it. I have approximately played 13 competitive games and I only won 1. My average competitive KD is around 40%.

I have searched links on the different ranking they provide in CS:GO. However, I have some questions regarding the ranking system:

Do they have a default rank when you reached 10 competitive wins?  Will they allocate you to any of the ranks or a default rank? Next, based on how I have done as mentioned above, does anyone have a idea what rank would I be in?

Comment: Related: [How do you rank up?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/236437/4797)

Answer (score 2):

No one knows what your rank will be until you win 10 competitive matches.
If you want to win matches you have to find some friends(good players) with whom you can have good communication in the match

Answer (score 1):

It's based on wins when you're still being placed, if you win 10 consecutive games, you are placed in LEM, and the more you lose, the more you move down from that. You cannot start higher than LEM. If you get a bad starting rank, it doesn't mean you're doomed. I started in Silver 4, ranked up to Distinguished Master Guardian within a month.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default rank. You will be ranked based upon how well you played, after you won at least ten matches in competitive mode.

No one can know which rank you will be in yet, because you just won one right now. Maybe you will win the next nine matches. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no default rank, your rank depends on your Win/Lose ratio, and you need at least to have 10 competitive wins to have your rank shown.

Answer (score 0):

Like these guys said, there is no default rank. But what I have found was that the very first match you play(which you have already played) is against Silver Elite Master or Gold Nova 1, then the way you play determines where that rank will steer. If you play fairly well but lose the matches, you may go down the ranks, but if you play good, you can move up. For example, I made a smurf account to play on, and after my first match I have found out I was playing against Gold Nova Masters(I am Legendary Eagle on my main xD).

It all depends on how you play, but losses may drive your rank down even if you are really good...