# How do you rank up?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I play Counter-Strike: Global Offensive and, at the moment, I'm rank silver 2. I usually get about 20 kills a game and I win about half of my games. When can I expect to rank up?

Comment: Related: [How does the CS:GO ranking system work?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85680/4797)

Answer (score 13):

*This answer is based on opinions from the community rather than facts provided by Valve.*

### The official answer would be: We don't know.

---

Kills do nothing when it comes to ranks.
The only thing that matters is whether you win or lose **rounds**.

Lose = you lose points (even with scoring an ace)
Win = you get points (even without killing anyone)

So if you're top scorer on your team and still don't manage to win more than you lose you'll have a hard time getting promoted. It's possible though.

---

How many points you get (or lose) depends on your current ranking (calculated in a system based on glicko2`*`), the sum of your teams points and sum of your opponents points, and whether or not you are MVP`**` in that round.

`*` [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2g3r4c/the_ultimate_guide_to_csgo_ranking/ckfhfir)
`**` MVP will be awarded to the best performing player from the winning team. Usually defined by good teamwork (Bomb handling, kills, assists,..).

Comment: Source for glicko2: https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2g3r4c/the_ultimate_guide_to_csgo_ranking/ckfhfir

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding, the ranking system of CS-GO is not only reliant on your kills. This is of own experience and research when I asked myself a similar question.

When you have a high K-D ratio and a high value to the team (for instance winning a round for your team by planting or defusing the bomb or by getting the final kill and so on so forth). This can result in being the MVP, thus improving your point gain for that round. It works similar (if not the same) to the Elo point system.

If you want a heavily detailed description of how the system works I found my understanding from an article I found on the Steam Community site.

I hope this link helps:
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=312582297

Best of luck man.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but here at Arqade.SE we usually prefer the posts  to contain the actual answers, rather than just the link to it. This way, if the link goes down, we still have something to rely on. Can you elaborate on how the OP will level up? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, understandable. From my understanding, the ranking system of CS-GO is not only reliant on your kills. This is of own experience and research when I asked myself a similar question. It tends to rank you up after quite a few games, and when you have a higher K-D ratio and a high value to the team. For instance winning a round for your team by planting the bomb or by getting the final kill and so on so forth.

Comment: The reason for the link is that I do not have extensive knowledge on the subject, but I read this article and it really helped me understand it more. So did not want to show the information as my own. And the answer can get quite detailed and long.

Comment: Linking to your source and calling it your source should suffice. (As in "Source:  http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=312582297 ") We certailty don't mind links, but we would perfer if the answer would have more than **just** the link.

Comment: It's alright if you extract the relevant info into the question as long as you cite the source. The link is there, so you're halfway there already. You just need to say who's the source in the link title and you're golden. Want to try it? I'll trade that for an upvote.

Comment: Would that suffice?

Comment: `It tends to rank you up after quite a few games, and when you have a higher K-D ratio and a high value to the team` is misleading. Good performance will get you MVP, which grants more points% after winning a round. Only one player at a time can be MVP though. So if you're really good and someone else is just a bit better you still get nothing extra.

Comment: Most definitely will. Thanks, Daniel! +1

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to know.

Most of the ranking system is a black box. Valve has not made anything other than the fact that they use a modified glicko-2 algorithm public.

It is theorized that your rank is modified on a round by round basis and not based on match wins/losses. It is also theorized that some of your stats and MVP stars are taking into account.

Answer (score 0):

From my own personal experience in the game, the way I knew I was going to rank up out of Silver was when I started playing a lot of Gold Novas

Answer (score -2):

The way to level up in the ranks is to win a lot of competitive games. Lose too many games and you will go down in rank.

I hope this helped. Good luck.