# How do promotion/demotion work in CSGO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I didn't play CSGO for a few months, and now that I came back to it, I'm stuck on the lowest ranking.

I must have played 15 games, not all wins, but still there was some, but I'm still with one stripe.

So how does the ranking work? Can I see how far I am to ranking up?

Comment: I've never seen any method to tell how close you are to ranking up.  Approximately what % were wins and how many total ranked wins do you have?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for in an answer: https://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/618459109266074446/?l=english.  If it is, I can formulate it into one.

Comment: Wins would be 60/40, but i am usually 1st or 2nd fragger in my team

Comment: @Fredy31 Place on your team doesn't matter AFAIK.  The round score definitely does (see the answer given).  ~15 games with 60% win isn't a whole lot more wins than losses.  Assuming you already have a good number of wins, I'm not surprised it didn't have a noticeable effect on rating yet.  Just keep playing with 60% win rate and you will climb eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When playing competitive matchmaking for the **first time** you need **10 wins or draws** in order to get your initial skill group.

After a certain amount of **inactivity** (4 weeks of not participating in competitive) you'll show as unranked again. This time your ranking is only hidden, not gone. After **another win or draw** you will see your badge again.

If you want a rank-up you can't tell. This is all about your team's performance in *every* game. Losing 16-1 has still a bigger impact than winning 3 times 16-14.

[This answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236437/how-do-you-rank-up/236443#236443) should help a bit.

Comment: But is there a way to see your exact MMR?

Comment: no :/ I wish there would